# Exception while launching telephone number in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here is what I tried.

```
_launchURL() async {
    if (await canLaunch("tel://125436512436")) {
      await launch("tel://125436512436");
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch';
    }
  }
```

But I keep getting exceptions for the same.I have imported the url_launcher package and the same is working for other strings.I am getting the below exception only when I am trying to launch a number.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I tried the same without the two // also in the URL, still getting the same exception.

Comment: Is there any additional error output like a stack trace?

Comment: hi Gunter, I was trying it in the emulator.

Comment: I tried it on the device, and it is working.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.